# How to give space between the text in zend from?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Here i have some text and slecect boxes..

Here i am attaching picture which is looks like and i need the code in zend from..

Regards
kiran[image]

Comment: Nope..i am trying but i didnt get any idea..so please give me some idea how to write?

Comment: Look at some screencasts if you're not quite sure on how to do things : http://www.zendcasts.com/category/screencasts/getting-started/forms-getting-started/ or http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework are good starting points to learn ZF.

Answer (score 0):

Set decorators to ViewHelper and Label and wrapping htmlTag decorator (being span with ID for example). Then do the styling in CSS :)